i have a problem when using input and while loop
my problem is that when inputting an invalid answer in leength it.s supposed to ask again and work after inputing again it just stops and don't do the turtle draw i want the input to continue and the while to work after giving an invalid answer
this is the code
from turtle import *
nasfk=range(1,400)
afnsj=[str(ggg)for ggg in nasfk]
def answer():
    print("this is not a valid answer")
def turtle():
    bgcolor('darkorchid1')
    turtlesize(2,3,0)
    color('red')#drawing and outline
    fillcolor('aquamarine')#inside turtle
def square(length):
    for i in range(4):
        forward(length)
        left(90)   
choose=input("choose(square,rectanle,triangle,polygon)")
if choose=='square':
   leength=input('enter the length(int)(1-400)')
   while leength.isnumeric():
     x=int(leength)
     turtle()
     square(x)
     done()
     break
   while leength not in afnsj:
     answer()
     leength=input('enter the length(int)(1-400)')

(as far as i know it is supposed to continue because of the while and i tried it in another code and it worked)(i am still a beginner)

Shouldn't you check if leength is in the list before you call square(x)?

Your first while loop never iterates, since it contains an unconditional break. So it's equivalent to if.

Why do you need afnsj? Just use if 1 <= x <= 400:

You should use only one while loop which should loop if something is not right and then repeatedly asks for input. The loop is left when the input is valid and then the code to process this input should follow after the loop.

Please put your code into https://black.vercel.app/ and use non-keyboard smashing variable names so others can read it. Function names should be actions (verbs), not nouns, unless they're getters, which these aren't.
